# Algorithm of generalized fibonacci

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

id like to have Generalizations of Fibonacci in recursive
i mean if i give first two numbers can get the *n* number from it

for example get 1 99 4 as input and your output be 199 
this means that the array is 1 , 99 , 100 , 199 , 299 , ...
and we need the 4th number
Could you give me some advice or suggest a way to solve the problem or create a code for it?

Comment: Just take any Fibonacci code and change the first two numbers to be the inputs you pass in.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, other than it seems you want someone to write some code for you. This also feels like a homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yea it seems works tnx i think i forgot to keep it simple stupid

Comment: @jdv i got my answer tnx 4 your reply ,actually i had a homework for recursive fibonacci but i try to achieve recursive form of generalized algorithm too